# My insert in PHP is not working

Tags: php, mysql

[here is the html code](http://jsfiddle.net/nR29B/751)I have a problem inserting into my databese through my PHP code and this is what I have:

```
//Here is where I make my connection
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$db = 'rafe_test';
```

i test my connection here:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("$dbhost", "$username", "$password","$db") or die ("no se conecto");

if(!mysqli_select_db($conn,$db))
{
    echo'database not selected';
}

// here is where i initialize my vars


$id_Folio = isset($_POST['idfolio']) ? $_POST['idfolio'] : '';
$fecha_Folio = isset($_POST['fechafolio']) ? $_POST['fechafolio'] : '';
$n_Maquinas = isset($_POST['nmaquinas']) ? $_POST['nmaquinas'] : '';
$desc_Pedido = isset($_POST['descpedido']) ? $_POST['descpedido'] : '';

$servicio1 = isset($_POST['servicio[]']) ? $_POST['servicio[]'] : '';
$servicio2 = isset($_POST['servicio[]']) ? $_POST['servicio[]'] : '';
$servicio3 = isset($_POST['servicio[]']) ? $_POST['servicio[]'] : '';
$servicio4 = isset($_POST['servicio[]']) ? $_POST['servicio[]'] : '';   
$fechaDeFinalizacion = isset($_POST['fechadefinalizacion']) ? $_POST['fechadefinalizacion'] : '';   
$logisticaDesc = isset($_POST['logisticadesc']) ? $_POST['logisticadesc'] : '';

$envio1 = isset($_POST['envio[]']) ? $_POST['envio[]'] : '';
$fechaEntregaReporte = isset($_POST['fechadeEntregaReporte']) ? $_POST['fechadeEntregaReporte'] : '';
$envio2 = isset($_POST['descripcionServicio']) ? $_POST['descripcionServicio'] : '';
```

here is where i think i have the problem because of my little alert down there:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO reportes (idFolio, fechaFolio, nMaquinas, descPedido, tareaLogistica1
,tareaLogistica2,tareaLogistica3,tareaLogistica4,tareaLogistica5Date,descLogistica,tareaServicio1,
tareaServicio2Date,descripcionServicio) VALUE 
    ('$id_Folio','$fecha_Folio','$n_Maquinas','$desc_Pedido','$servicio1','$servicio2', '$servicio3','$servicio4','$fechaDeFinalizacion','$logisticaDesc','$envio1' ,'$fechaEntregaReporte' ,'$envio2')";

if(!mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
{
    echo'not inserted';
} 
else
{           
    echo'inserted';
}
```

Comment: VALUES and not VALUE

Comment: @DevMan 2nd time in 2 days where people say that. In MySQL, both are valid http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html `INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name,...)] 
    [(col_name,...)]
    {VALUES | VALUE}` - So please lose that misconception.

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: without seeing what the HTML forms looks like, is impossible to answer. Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: You're using arrays here `$_POST['xxx[]']` so those could be failing you. Feel free to jump in here at anytime, while updating your question to show us what the HTML form looks like. Till then, you've been given a (*wrong*) answer below. Ask them. I've done enough. Good luck.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nR29B/751/ this is my code

Comment: hahaha im pretty new here and posting, sorry for the downvotes XD

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($conn))` to `mysqli_query()`. That is the best we can offer you. Good luck.

Comment: @Fred-ii- OK thanks for mentioning that you heard it for the second time in two days but how am I supposed to know that you're hearing it for the second time in two days? :0)

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong keyword. It's `VALUES`

Comment: In MySQL, both are valid http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html `INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name,...)] 
    [(col_name,...)]
    {VALUES | VALUE}` - Whover and why you guys are upvoting this, is beyond me.